# Sleep() function causes the program to crash in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winsock

I tried to use Winsock to implement a socket, and added a `Sleep(40)` statement after `WSACleanup()`. After the compilation, when I click on the Local Windows Debugger button, Visual Studio reports an error:

[image]

But, when `Sleep(40)` statement is deleted，the program works well.

[image]

I searched the user guide of the `Sleep()` function and found no restrictions.

Did I miss some settings in Visual Studio 2015? How do I solve this?

Comment: I seriously doubt that either Sleep(), Winsock, or the debugger behave as you have described. Something else must be going on.

Comment: Try  rebuilding the project and check the output message. Is there any error?

Comment: My guess would be an antivirus scanner getting in the way

Comment: Are there any antivirus software installed? Some antivirus  will have influence on exe with Sleep().